# flash slider or what?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash

Probably for someones this question is trivial but i can't remember which is the correct name
for this flash slider with products from [here](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/index.asp)

The original name is not slider but something else...

The second question: do you know any flex or javascript "slider" like this which is free?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called an Image Slider.

Here is an open source one:
http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/flash-image-scroller/

Here is how to make one:
http://www.flash-slide-show.com/flash-gallery-tutorial/flash-image-scroller-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks. I've found the "original" name: carousel. However your answer is helpfull. Thanks again.